# Is having Unity/awesome wm together possible? how can I do this?

Tags: unity, awesome

I would like to have the menus, sidebar,the HUD, and the user friendliness ubuntu offers but I would like the window control and the window tiling capabilities of awesome together. Google has not helped me much in my search. Is this possible? how can I go about doing this?

Comment: i use openbox WM. but I can't use unity and openbox together. if it is possible that would be great. But i think its impossible.

Comment: I believe you can get a bunch of good tiling functionality from Compiz. Install Compiz Config. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompizConfig

Comment: I think the best situation right now is to use Awesome with Gnome: http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quickly_Setting_up_Awesome_with_Gnome . I would love to have the Unity Dash with Awesome though and maybe the sidebar icons too but I'd rather have tiling than a fancy search box. I think there are other tools that do similar things to the Dash though.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible, Unity needs Compiz as it's a plugin, sorry!